# How to return two arrays modified from a function with memcpy?

Tags: c++, c

I try to copy two arrays thanks to a function and memcpy. Test function has to return two arrays modified.

The first array is correctly copied but when I try to do the same thing with memcpy to the second, there is a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

**Example code:**

```
void test(uint8_t* payload, uint8_t* element_size){
  uint8_t tab[2];
  tab[0] = 1;
  tab[1] = 2;
  memcpy(payload, tab, sizeof(tab));
  memcpy(element_size, tab, sizeof(tab));
}

int main(){
      uint8_t* tab1;
      uint8_t* tab2;

      test(tab1, tab2);

      return 0;
}
```

What is the problem ? I don't understand this error.

Comment: You have uninitialized pointers `tab1` and `tab2` - you need to point them at valid, sufficient memory (e.g.: allocated using `new`)

Comment: Though using raw arrays (prefer `std::vector` and `std::array`) and pointers (prefer smart pointers) is not the right choice in most situations

Comment: Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. Or if the size is fixed at compile-time maybe [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Your code looks like C than C++. Are you sure the C++ tag is correct?

Comment: There must be a duplicate for this — in C, copying to uninitialized pointers is depressingly common.  It isn't clear why C++ is involved; dual-tagging questions as C and C++ is frequently incorrect, and this seems to one of those frequent times.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to copy two arrays
>
> What is the problem ?

The problem is that there are no "two arrays" in your program. There's just one array, `tab` that is local to the `test` function.

Your program uses the values of `tab1` and `tab2` pointers without initializing them. Therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> ```
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```
>
> I don't understand this error.

The error means that your program tried to access memory segment that it wasn't supposed to, and the operating system killed the process as a result. It is a way of the OS to prevent arbitrary behaviour of the program. This sometimes happens when the program has undefined behaviour.

---

Perhaps the simplest way to fix your program is to declare `tab1` and `tab2` as arrays, rather than as uninitialized pointers:

```
uint8_t tab1[2];
uint8_t tab2[2];
```

Comment: It just an example but in my code, it's not an array at a fixed number but it is a variable. We can't know the size of tab1 and tab2.

Comment: @pabob in that case, the reason why your example is wrong is not necessarily the reason why that other code is wrong. You should create a [mcve]. You do have to know that the size of the arrays is at least 2 octets. Otherwise you overflow them.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the sample code a bit shows both error and solution

```
void test(int* payload, int* element_size){
  int tab[2];
  tab[0] = 1;
  tab[1] = 2;
  memcpy(payload, tab, sizeof(tab));
  tab[1] = 4;
  memcpy(element_size, tab, sizeof(tab));
}

int main(){
      int* tab1; // just a pointer.
      int* tab2;

      printf ("Before tab1=%x, tab2=%x\n",tab1,tab2);

    tab1 = malloc(2*sizeof(int)); // Now the pointer points to some storage
    tab2 = malloc(2*sizeof(int));

      test(tab1, tab2); // Pass addresses to int storage locations

      printf ("After tab1=%x, tab2=%x\n",tab1,tab2);

      printf ("tab1[0]=%d, tab1[1]=%d\n",*tab1,*tab1+1);
      printf ("tab2[0]=%d, tab2[1]=%d\n",tab2[0],tab2[1]);

      return 0;
      }
```

When run this gives

```
$ ./ptr3
Before tab1=ea32daf8, tab2=0
After tab1=5f4002e0, tab2=5f400340
tab1[0]=1, tab1[1]=2
tab2[0]=1, tab2[1]=4
```

tab2 is an undefined variable and starts as value 0.
The memcpy tries to copy data to memory location 0 and this is the segmentation violation.  When the pointers are pointed towards some storage locations with Malloc the memcopy s work.

In the subroutine 'tab' is an array of 2 ints but tab1 and tab2 are single pointer locations in the body of the code. Memcpy uses the size of the local structure tab[2] and assumes the destination payload (which is the address of a pair of int) is big enough.
This could become a classic buffer overrun error.

HINT1 Best not to use the same name 'tab' for two very different structures.
HINT2 memcpy src and destination sizes need to be the same or checked for overruns.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(int))` allocating memory for a single `int` is pointless, and here it is even totally wrong, because `test` copies 2 `int`s but the memory portions where `tab1`and `tab2` point to can only hold one `int`. Please consider to overwork your answer, otherwise it is likely to be downvoted.

Comment: Yes I see that  @MichaelWalz - thus the words in the answer  "This is a classic buffer overrun error." 

More complete/correct answers would have main as

      `tab1 = malloc(2*sizeof(int)); // Now the pointer points to some storage
      tab2 = malloc(2*sizeof(int));

      test(tab1, tab2); // Pass addresses to int storage locations

      printf ("After tab1=%x, tab2=%x\n",tab1,tab2);

      printf ("tab1[0]=%d, tab1[1]=%d\n",*tab1,*tab1+1);
      printf ("tab2[0]=%d, tab2[1]=%d\n",tab2[0],tab2[1]);`